# How to get check particular checkboxes by default based on some values in angular 7

Tags: html, css, typescript, angular7

I have a checkboxes and selectbox whose values are coming from loop,but here I need to get some checkboxes checked by default based on an array of object.Here checkbox and selectbox value is coming from usersg and usersr variable.But the checked and selected by default should be from variable usersg_checked and usersr_selected inside ngOnInit(). Here is the code below

### home.component.html

```
<p *ngFor="let group of usersg"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked.id" value="{{group.id}}" />{{group.name}}</p>

<p><select><option *ngFor="let role of usersr" value="{{role.id}}">{{role.name}}</option></select></p>
```

### home.component.html

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonserviceService } from './../utilities/services/commonservice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    submitted = false;
    usersg_checked:any;
    usersr_selected:any;

 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {


     }
public usersg = [{"id":1,"name":"test1"},{"id":2,"name":"test2"},{"id":3,"name":"test3"},{"id":4,"name":"test4"}];

public usersr = [{"id":1,"name":"test1"},{"id":2,"name":"test2"}];


  ngOnInit() {
this.usersg_checked = [{"id":1,"name":"test1"},{"id":2,"name":"test2"}];

this.usersr_selected = [{"id":1,"name":"test1"}];


  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `isChecked()` method in component to check if a checkbox must be selected.

**Component:**

```
isChecked(id) {
  return this.usersg_checked.some(item => item.id === id);
}
```

**Template:**

```
<p *ngFor="let group of usersg">
  <input type="checkbox" [checked]="isChecked(group.id)" value="{{group.id}}" />{{group.name}}
</p>
```

For `<select>` elements better to use `[(ngModel)]`.

**Template:**

```
<p><select [(ngModel)]="usersr_selected.id">
   <option *ngFor="let role of usersr" value="{{role.id}}">{{role.name}}</option> 
</select></p>
```

**Component:**

And change `usersr_selected` to an object.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.usersr_selected = {"id":1,"name":"test1"};
}
```

If `usersr_selected` is an array, use the first element of the array as `NgModel`.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.usersr_selected = this.usersr_selected[0];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer both are working fine but for select {"id":1,"name":"test1"}; needs to be array of object like [{"id":1,"name":"test1"}];  in my case,that is coming from API in my project,I cannot change it.

Comment: @UIAPPDEVELOPER - Check out my edited answer and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: In my project its showing cannot read property some of undefined

Comment: @UIAPPDEVELOPER - It means you don't have `this.usersg_checked` data available when view is rendered. Add `*ngIf` like `<ng-container *ngIf="usersg_checked"> <p *ngFor="let group of usersg"> ... </p></ng-container>`. Let me know if you are still having any errors.